# JQuery $ not found with IE but Chrome is fine. Works local in IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

Our company is still officially on IE 9. When I developed my new web app, I tested it locally Visual Studio 2015 and with IIS Express with both IE 9 and Chrome, and both worked fine. However, when I go to deploy it to an Windows 2012 IIS 8 web server, users using IE 9 get an error that teh $ function for JQuery cannot be found. Yet, Chrome users have no issues at all.

I should be able to use jQuery with IE. Why would it work with IE running locally but not when deployed to a web server? If there was a deployment with jQuery scripts not being found in the right folder, then I would expected Chrome users to also have an issue, but they do not.

Any idea on how to resolve the issue with IE 9 users or where to start looking more closely?

I am bundling jQuery in my ASP.NET MVC app as follows:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

In DEV TOols, I think it looks like it loaded:

```
Key Value
User-Agent  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Connection  Keep-Alive
Referer http://myserver:83/
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Request GET /bundles/jqueryval?v=xeePbbT2vC4pL1LKONgpwwYRtT6DJgMoJ9YgtVoYbXI1 HTTP/1.1
If-Modified-Since   Fri, 08 Jul 2016 14:51:18 GMT
Accept-Language en-US
Host    myserver:83
Cookie  ASP.NET_SessionId=bavmuwmb0z30tx25bxw2vuxb
Accept  */*
```

I get a flurry of error messages including

```
Line: 1
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Line: 1
Error: 'jQuery' is undefined
```

**Update:**

I find this very interesting an unexpected:

If I access the site via using either the server name or a "friendly" DNS URL, I get the above error. If I instead use the IP address, the site works in IE 9.

I would have expected that the first 2 approaches, server name and DNS, both resolve to an the  IP address and if they both resolved to the same IP address, that all 3 would work the same. But they didn't. jQuery only works with IE if the IP is used but Chrome works in all cases. I'm stumped.

1. servername
2. www.mysite.com
3. 1.2.3.4

Comment: What is the jQuery lib version? Maybe an upgrade would fix this.

Comment: @Louys: 2.2.3 Thanks

Comment: Upgrade would not change anything. Make sure file is loading in dev tools network

Comment: Please see my update to my original post.